# CoreBluetooth writing value to cached peripheral

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

So I'm working with two apps. One acts as the central, the other is the peripheral. There could be more than one devices that act as the peripheral. When the Central launches, it begins scanning for peripherals that are running a service I call `UUIDService`. This service has two characteristics: `vendorUUID` (read) and `totalAmount` (write).

When the Peripheral launches, it begins advertising `UUIDService` with it's `-[UIDevice identifierForVendor]` string as the value for `vedorUUID` and `nil` for `totalAmount.`

On Central, I have a singleton called `BluetoothManager` which holds a mutable array called `connectedUsers` to keep track of peripherals that are connected to the central. This is an array of `BTUser` objects which has two properties: uuid (NSString) and periph (CBPeripheral).

When Central discovers a peripheral, it creates the user object and fills in the reference to `periph`:

```
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{    
    NSLog(@"Discovered periph advertising UUID Service");
    BTUser* user = [[BTUser alloc] init];
    user.periph = peripheral;

    [_centralManager connectPeripheral:user.periph options:nil];

    [_connectedUsers addObject:user];

    NSLog(@"User periph: %@", user.periph.identifier);

}
```

This block of code works. `_connectedUsers` now contains one `BTUser` with a `periph`. Then it connects:

```
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{

    NSLog(@"Connected periph: %@", peripheral.name);

    BTUser* thisUser;
    for (BTUser* user in _connectedUsers)
    {
        if ([user.periph.identifier isEqual: peripheral.identifier])
        {
            thisUser = user;
            break;
        }
    }

    thisUser.periph.delegate = self;
    [thisUser.periph discoverServices:@[_uuidServiceUUID]];

}
```

I've confirmed this works, and the peripheral goes on to discover the service and and related characteristics. The issue I'm running into is when I go to use the reference to the peripheral to write to `totalAmount`.

```
-(void)initializePaymentWithUser:(BTUser*)user forAmount:(CGFloat)amount
{
    _isListeningForUsers = NO;

    [self stopScanningForUsers];
    NSLog(@"disconnecting from all other users");
    for (BTUser* u in _connectedUsers)
    {
        if (![u isEqual:user])
        {
            [u disconnectFromCentral:_centralManager];
        }
    }

    CBService* uuidService = user.periph.services[0];
    for (CBCharacteristic* cha in uuidService.characteristics)
    {
        if ([cha.UUID isEqual:_uuidServiceTotalAmountUUID])
        {
            NSLog(@"Writing total amount %.2f", amount);
            NSData* data = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", amount] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [user.periph writeValue:data
                  forCharacteristic:cha
                               type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];

            break;
        }
    }

}
```

It makes it to the block that writes the value, and `user.periph` still has the same `-[CBPeripheral identifier]` as it did when it originally connected. But I'm getting the error:

```
CoreBluetooth[WARNING] <CBPeripheral: 0x14ed28c0 identifier = B4CB35CC-2C78-7543-B083-E0B373EF66D0, Name = "iPhone", state = connected> is not a valid peripheral
```

And the peripheral never calls `-peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error`.

For completion to this questions, this is the block of code from the Peripheral responsible for advertising the `UUIDService`:

```
-(void)advertiseVendorUUID:(NSString*)uuid
     paymentInitiatedBlock:(DOBluetoothPeripheralBlock)completion
{
    _uuidService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType: _uuidServiceUUID
                                                  primary:YES];
    NSLog(@"Adding vendor id to characteristic: %@", uuid);
    NSData* vendorData = [uuid dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    _uuidServiceVendorUUIDChar = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:_uuidServiceVendorUUIDUUID
                                                                    properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
                                                                         value:vendorData
                                                                   permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
    _uuidServiceTotalAmountChar = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:_uuidServiceTotalAmountUUID
                                                                     properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite
                                                                          value:nil
                                                                    permissions:CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];

    _uuidService.characteristics = @[_uuidServiceVendorUUIDChar, _uuidServiceTotalAmountChar];

    [_peripheralManager addService:_uuidService];
    [_peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: @[_uuidService.UUID],
                                           CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: @"UUID"}];
}
```

Comment: Did you try writing the data immediately after (or instead of) discovering the services?

Comment: If nothing interesting is happening in your stopScanningForUsers and disconnectFromCentral: methods I'd say the reason isn't related to your code.  In your centralManagerDidUpdateState: are you continuing to hold onto your BTUser references (You should nil all peripheral references if the central manager state changes and do a new scan once the state returns to CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)?  You may also try reseting the network settings of your development devices.